# Keras: Export Model File is Incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model called `model` using a Tensorflow backend and I'm trying to save it in an ML Engine-friendly format.  After googling around, here's my attempt:

```
    from tensorflow import saved_model
    import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

    K.clear_session()
    sess = tf.Session()
    K.set_session(sess)

    # build a copy but without the learning nodes
    K.set_learning_phase(0)  # disables creation of dropout

    model_builder = saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("exported_model")
    inputs = {
        'input': saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.input)
    }
    outputs = {
        'output': saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.output)
    }
    signature_def = saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs=inputs,
        outputs=outputs,
        method_name=saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
    )
    model_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        K.get_session(),
        tags=[saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_def
                           })
    model_builder.save()
```

The output is `saved_model.pb` but it's less than 1 MB when the `model.h5` file is over 100MB.  So I suspect it isn't saving the weights of my model?

Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!